# Is it possible to create custom file names with Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I have a set of tags in my posts.

For example in `posts/somepost.md`:

```
---
name: Some Post
tags: ["tag_a", "tag_b"]
---
```

I would like to render pages based on the tags dynamically. Like: `tags/tag_a.html`, `tags/tag_b.html`, etcetera. Of course, the content of those pages will contain the posts with those tags.

How is this called in Jekyll, and/or what would be a workaround to achieve this?

Comment: You use plugin like this one : https://github.com/pattex/jekyll-tagging

Comment: You can also create a collection with the tags and refer to them very easily in a CMS like CloudCannon. That is more in line with the Jekyll architecture IMO.

Comment: Thanks, I agree @JoostS, can I somehow capture the collection on rendering the page to create custom pages?

Comment: Collections create pages by default. Just make sure `output` is set to `true` in the _config.yml (again: default).